# Split dataset into Train/Validation/Test for Object Detection

Tags: datasets, object-detection, yolo

I have a dataset for Object Detection with YOLO format labels, each imagine can have occurences of different classes and multiple occurences of the same class.

How can the dataset be divided into Training, Validation, and Test sets so that each contains about the same percentage of occurences per class?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the scikit learn `train_test_split()` by passing the `stratify` argument with the class value.

Comment: This can become a more complicated problem , if there is imbalance in the distribution of classes.